# Multiple puppet requires

Tags: puppet

Hi I'd like to make a puppet resource/task dependent on multiple other tasks.

For example:

```
file{'~/foo':}
file{'~/bar':}
file{'~/foobar':
  require => File['~foo'],
  require => File['~bar']
}
```

What's the correct syntax to define this?

Thanks

Answer (score 61):

From [Language: Data Types](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_datatypes.html#arrays)

Resource attributes which can optionally accept multiple values (including the relationship metaparameters) expect those values in an array.

```
file{'~/foo':}
file{'~/bar':}
file{'~/foobar':
  require => [ File['~foo'], File['~bar'] ]
}
```

Comment: where the resources are the same type as here you can say File[ '~foo', '~bar' ]. I found this post because I wanted to have have a resource dependent of User *and* FIle.